# Not for me/Not to me

Tags: grammar, idioms, idiomatic-language

A: Isn't it hard to make ice cream?

B: **Not for me.** / **Not to me.**

I haven't been able to find the answer to this, so... Would both be natural in the given context or is only one correct? Do they mean different things?

Answer (score 4):

Here is my answer as a native British English speaker.

The question asked "A: Isn't it hard to make ice cream?" makes perfect sense.

For the purposes of my answer, I'm going to expand it to read "A: Isn't it hard **for anyone** to make ice cream?"

"Not for me" is a shortened way of saying "It is **not** hard **for me** to make ice cream". You would never say "It is not hard to me to make ice cream".

If the first question had been "Doesn't ice cream taste too sweet?", then the response might have been "Not to me". This is a shortened version of "Ice cream does **not** taste too sweet **to me**"